# Flutter "Project Creation Error" on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm using Windows 10, Android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1.

When I create 'new flutter project' in android studio (Windows),
message box says,

```
Project Creation Error
Flutter create command was unsuccessful
```

Then when I click 'run flutter doctor', it says

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

It's still same after `flutter channel master` `flutter upgrade`.

I installed Git and added environment variables.
`C:\Windows\System32` `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` `C:\flutter\bin`

When I use `flutter --version`, `flutter doctor` in windows terminal, it works fine.
[`flutter --version` (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3poT.png)

`flutter create ...` works fine too.

But I want to fix 'Android Studio - new flutter project' properly.

I repeated uninstalling and reinstalling everything 3 times, but still not working.

It's driving me crazy.. How can I solve this??

Comment: crazy? come on, how many projects do you create every day? personally I always run `flutter create ...` from the command line as it gives me the full control on how project is created...

Comment: @pskink   Nice point of view.  
You are right, but I'm worried of something going wrong afterwards.  
Is it ok if I do not fix that problem?

Comment: i don't know, maybe there is more info in the android studio logs?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: I stuck with this issue right now, Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Running Android Studio with Admin Privileges (Run as Administrator) fix this issue, Very Weird. I'm still looking for the reason.

My Paths:

```
C:\flutter-sdk\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd
%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin
%ProgramFiles%\Git\mingw64\bin
```